# Qt : How to alternate alignment of a QTextEdit in a QVBoxLayout?

Tags: c++, qt, layout, alignment, qvboxlayout

I would like to add QTextEdit widgets in a layout and alternate the alignment

```
QVBoxLayout *lt = new QVBoxLayout;

/* I would like to align them like that :
   -------------
   | One       |
   |       Two |
   | Three     |
   |      Four |
   | Five      |
   ------------
*/

for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    text1 = new QTextEdit;
    text1->setText("Hello world !" + QString::number(i));
    text1->setMaximumSize(100,30);
    lt->addWidget(text1);
    lt->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);

    if(i%2)
    {
        lt->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight);
    }
    else
    {
        lt->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);
    }
}

setLayout(lt);
```

However, the QTextEdits, are all align on the left.

Is there a solution to my problem ?

Comment: Do you want to lay out your five widgets in the VBox as (ok, so I can't draw a table in comments) laid out right, then left, or do you want the *contents* of the textedits to be right- or left-aligned?

Comment: .. for the contents, you want to call `text1->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight)`, and not the alignment on the layout. To push the widgets around inside the VBoxLayout, you'll need an QHboxLayout around each TextEdit to do that alignment (or use a 3-column grid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checking in the [Qt doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#addWidget) i found that I just needed to add some arguments when adding my widget in the QVBoxLayout
Here is the code :

```
QVBoxLayout *lt = new QVBoxLayout;

for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    text1 = new QTextEdit;
    text1->setText("Hello world !" + QString::number(i));
    text1->setMaximumSize(100,30);
    
    if(i%2)
    {
        lt->addWidget(text1, 0, Qt::AlignRight);
    }
    else
    {
        lt->addWidget(text1, 0, Qt::AlignLeft);
    }
}
```